Topics for undergraduate student seminar on algebraic geometry
I am a masters student, and chatting with undergraduates and a couple professors we agreed on (trying to organize) a student-level seminar on algebraic geometry. Our main motivation is that, while we do have an Algebraic Varieties course available (think at the level of Fulton, or Hartshorn Ch. 1), we do not have a formal instance to keep learning as a group.
The things we've got at our hand are a research-level seminar (which is not intended for students), and the usual recommendation to read Hartshorne/Vakil for the next 1–3 years. While there is merit to the second task, it is not an adequate fit: we are a varied group (think of people interested in complex geometry, differential topology, arithmetic applications, etc) and while algebraic geometry is very adjacent to our interests, it is not the main focus of our academic path.
In my faculty three is a running Number Theory seminar at student-level, and it is very fun, accesible, and works like a charm. I'm thinking of something like this, but for algebraic geometry.
So, the question. Given this background, what do you think would be some fun topics to present in a seminar of this level?
Thanks!

Especially given that you have people interested in complex geometry and differential topology in your group, it could be interesting to learn some theory of Riemann surfaces. I don't know exactly what you cover in your course, but you could use Miranda's book on Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces. This gives you a preview of some of the material in Hartshorne's chapter 4, without using the language of schemes. In fact, the treatment here is of a more topological/analytic flavor.
